# How to run a single test case using mvn robotframework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to run a test case in robot framework using mvn robotframework. But when i do it runs all the testcases in the suite rather than a single testcase. 
I also tried to user robot testcase -testcase.robot.
It is also giving error.

Can anyone help regarding this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign run a test case by this command

Lets say we have a directory called Tests inside that directory we have Test.robot which contains 5 different test cases "Login" "Register" "Delete User" "Update User" "Random Test"

```
Tests
   |
   |_ Test.robot
```

You can use the following command the execute a single test cases

```
robot Tests/Test.robot -t "Login"
```

This command will only execute the Login test case

Comment: Actually the issue is not about running i guess. Please see the log below. It is giving following log.

Importing test library 'App.Utilities' failed: ImportError: No module named App
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /home/admin2/jython2.7.0/bin
  /home/admin2/jython2.7.0/Lib
  __classpath__
  __pyclasspath__/
  /home/admin2/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages
CLASSPATH:
  /home/admin2/jython2.7.0/jython.jar