# Is there any way to run a single robot framework testcase using maven and not the whole suite?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I want to run a single robot framework test but when i run through 
mvn robotframework:run command, it runs all the testcases present in acceptance/tests directory instead of the one specific testcase.

Is there anyway to run just a single testcase ??

Comment: You have asked the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55850913/how-to-run-a-single-test-case-using-mvn-robotframework/55851162#55851162